# Check for time component on a datacolumn

Tags: c#

Is there a way wherein I can stop the local time conversion only for the 2nd column in the datatable when serialization takes place? How can I determine that the 2nd column in the datatable has no time component and hence I will set the DateTimeMode of that column to UnSpecified instead of UnSpecifiedLocal

Answer (score 0):

```
       if (dataGridView1.Columns[1].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
        {  //dosomething
        }
```

this piece of code will check if the 2nd column is of the type DateTime. this is not failsafe.

Comment: Both the columns are of type DateTime.. but one column does not actually have a timecomponent.. The objective is to determine this.

Comment: then try to get the Cells and check if they are DateTime